# Zooming UIView inside a ScrollView via Pinch gesture on a Point

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, zooming

Due to some requirements I'm zomming `subview` of UIScrollView with `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and not using `UIScrollView`'s default zooming. In selector of gesture I resize my `subview` with a factor and reset `contentSize` of `UIScrollView`. It's working perfectly. The problem is that when I resize the `frame` of subview then it's increased or decreased in one direction. I want it to zoomin/zoomout on touched point like in a `UIScrollView` or in Gallery of iOS. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't see why you would have to override UIScrollView's default pinch, but in that case, you need to determine the center point of your pinch gesture, find out at which "eye coordinates" it's displaying, apply the zoom and then modify your `contentOffset` so that the point remains at the same "visible" location

Comment: @Ismael Well I had to do it this way and I hate it too. But nevertheless. I tried to do it as you suggested earlier but i could not implement the logic to compute the contentoffset after resizing.

Comment: I'm afraid that's exactly what you are missing, so you will either have to give it another shot, or find a way to use the default zooming behavior. Perhaps there's a way to solve your problem without manually handling pinch? Why did you have to use it?

Comment: I had to zoom only in horizontal direction and plus my zomming was unlimited. Actually I draw a graph with months on x-axis which after a specific zoom I chnage the x-axis to weeks and later on days. SO you see that this zooming will go on & on. That's why I had to zoom manually.

Comment: How are you positioning things after you do your zooming? Achieving an only horizontal zooming seems rather odd. Perhaps you can do with the built-in pinch gesture and resize your view's height on viewDidZoom: so that no vertical scrolling happens

Comment: It's actually not zooming, rather it's resizing to bring more content to display. After I resize my view then I redraaw it with setneedsdisplay.